# what is the mate equivalent of startxfce4?

Tags: xfce, mate

what is the mate equivalent of startxfce4?
Im trying to set up a remote desktop setup with tightvnc, but Im not sure how to replicate the instructions I am tentatively following, around mate, without xfce4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purposes of a VNC server (TightVNC especially, assuming you already have an X server running), `mate-session` for the MATE desktop should be be the equivalent of `startxfce4` for Xfce, much like GNOME's `gnome-session`.

Although this may not be the tutorial you are following, it is possible in a tutorial at [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-14-04) to replace `startxfce4 &` with `mate-session &` in the example `xstartup` file from Step Two in order to start the MATE desktop when the VNC server starts.

For the sake of answering the question in the title exactly, however, there is an important difference between the behaviors of `startxfce4` and `mate-session`. `startxfce4` starts an X server before launching the Xfce Desktop Environment, but `mate-session` merely starts MATE, requiring an X server to have been started beforehand. Thus, the actual MATE equivalent of `startxfce4` would be something like

```
export DISPLAY=:0
startx
mate-session
```

However, due to the behavior of `startx`, these cannot all be executed in one terminal. Instead, you could execute `startx` in one terminal (`tty1`, for example). Then, after switching to another terminal (`tty2`, for example), you could set the `DISPLAY` variable to the proper value and execute `mate-session`. Finally, you could switch back to wherever you started the X server (by doing `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`, for example, if you used `tty1`) to see the MATE desktop.